# Running total instead of individual total?

Tags: java

I'm required to develop a wages calculator application which calculates the total staff cost of a number of shop units per week and then prints the staff cost of each individual unit onto the screen. However, the program currently only prints a cumulative total for each unit onto the screen (ie. if the staff cost for unit one is £450 and the staff cost for unit two is £0 the program still prints the staff cost for unit two as £450 instead of £0). Any ideas how I can change my code to fix this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Task3Second {

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);    

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("M:\\4001COMP-CW1-Task3-Infile.txt"));
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("results.txt");

    String ShopUnit;
    int NoOfStaff;
    int HoursWorkedPerWeek;
    double HourlyRate;
    double TotalStaffCost = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double RecommendedMaximumStaffCost;

    System.out.println("Please enter the recommended maximum staff cost.");
    RecommendedMaximumStaffCost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The recommended maximum staff cost is £" + RecommendedMaximumStaffCost);
    System.out.println();
    outFile.println("The recommended maximum staff cost is £" + RecommendedMaximumStaffCost);

    while(inFile.hasNext()){
        count++;
        ShopUnit = inFile.nextLine();
    if(ShopUnit.startsWith("Unit")){
        NoOfStaff = inFile.nextInt();
        for(count = 0; count < NoOfStaff; count++){
            HoursWorkedPerWeek = inFile.nextInt();
            HourlyRate = inFile.nextDouble();
            TotalStaffCost = TotalStaffCost + (HoursWorkedPerWeek * HourlyRate);
        }
        if (TotalStaffCost < RecommendedMaximumStaffCost)
        {System.out.println("The total staff cost of " + ShopUnit + " is £" + TotalStaffCost + ", which is less than the recommended staff cost.");
        PrintWriter outFile1 = new PrintWriter("results.txt");
        outFile1.println("The total staff cost of " + ShopUnit + " is £" + TotalStaffCost);
        }else if (TotalStaffCost == RecommendedMaximumStaffCost)
        {System.out.println("The total staff cost of " + ShopUnit + " is £" + TotalStaffCost + ", which is equal to the recommended staff cost.");  
        }else {System.out.println("The total staff cost of " + ShopUnit + " is £" + TotalStaffCost + ", which is more than the recommended staff cost.");}

        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The total staff cost of all the shopping units is £" + TotalStaffCost);
    outFile.println("The total staff cost of all the shopping units is £" + TotalStaffCost);

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to calculate both a running total and a unit total:

1. Create a variable to hold the running total; maybe name it "runningTotal".  Initialize this to zero.
2. Create a variable to hold the unit total; maybe name it "unitTotal".
3. for all units perform the following:

   1. reset the unit total to zero.
   2. calculate the total for the current unit.
   3. display the total for the current unit.  This includes the option of storing the unit total in a collection for later display.
   4. add the unit total to the running total.
4. Display the running total.

In your code, you have one variable for total, the running total.  You need two variables; one for running total and one for unit total.

If "unit" is confusing, read it as "store".

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example of what this would look like?

Comment: How do you differentiate each store in your input?

Comment: 'Unit One', 'Unit Two' and so on, there are 9 units, as you can probably tell I'm new to programming